# Is is possible to grab the number of frames in a userform and the number of optionbuttons in a frame?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with 4 questions, 3 optionbuttons per question. If someone decides to change the design, I do not want them to have to edit the code. Is is possible, instead of my loops being (1 to 3) and (1 to 4), I want the loops to specify:

```
1 to # of frames
1 to # of questions in a frame
```

Here is my code below:

```
'Transfer information
For j = 1 To 4 'columns 1 to 4 (4 questions)
    For i = 1 To 3 '3 optionbutton in 1 question
        labelstrr = "OptionButton" & labelnum 'concatenation of optionbutton1,2,...,12.
        If Me.Controls(labelstrr).Value = True Then
        Cells(emptyRow, j).Value = i
        End If
        labelnum = labelnum + 1
    Next i
Next j
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is it always the same number of questions in a frame, i.e. if you know you have 6 questions and 2 frames then it's 3 in each frame?

Comment: Yes, it is always the same number of questions in a frame(3 at the moment), but that number of frames and the number of questions per frame can vary if someone decides to change the userform. But yes, the number of questions per frame will always be the same in each frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this loop, I don't think there is a quicker way. It returns the values in a message box but you could assign to a function or call a sub or just incorporate into other code, depends on what you are doing exactly.

```
Sub xx()

Dim c As Control, n1 As Long, n2 As Long

For Each c In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is msforms.OptionButton Then
        n1 = n1 + 1
    ElseIf TypeOf c Is msforms.Frame Then
        n2 = n2 + 1
    End If
Next c

MsgBox n1 & " option buttons in " & n2 & " frames (i.e. " & n1 / n2 & " questions per frame)"

End Sub
```