# ExcelUserForm with OptionButtons in a Frame - code to identify and use the NUMBER of the selected OptionButton

Tags: excel, radio-button, userform

```
`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'I have a UserForm that includes 2 Frames and 2 Command Buttons.
'The 2 Frames each hold 30 OptionButtons;
'           Frame1 has OptionButtons 1 through 30 and allows the user to
'           select which, of 30 bank accounts is the origin in a money transfer,
'           and Frame2 has 31 through 60 and similarly decides the destination Account in the transfer.
'The 2 CommandButtons are to execute the same idea, but in two different ways. I only need one.
'This code below is meant to display the name of the Range that is becoming FromAcc,
'           which is: ("LedgerTable" & [the Number of the OptionButton selected]).
'    The MsgBox is just for testing to make sure I get this part right;
'    it'll eventually get replaced with more code to execute.
'Many statements are commented-out because, -who wants to include ALL the buttons for just a test?  Right?

Dim FromAcc As Range

FromAcc = "No OptionButton has been selected."
'The FromAcc begins as that text because if, at the end, no OptionButton has been selected,
'then the MsgBox, whose message is determined by the value of FromAcc, is all prepared with the right message.
'So, I go off thinkin' I'm all clever, right?
'      ...Well then I thought I was really hot stuff when 
'              I came about the second method via CommandButton2. Watch.

'All of these statements check each individual OptionButton and set FromAcc as its own unique textstring.
'These textstrings are recognized Table names; Named Ranges within the Workbook.

If Frame1.OptionButton1.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable1"
If Frame1.OptionButton2.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable2"
If Frame1.OptionButton3.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable3"
If Frame1.OptionButton4.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable4"
If Frame1.OptionButton5.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable5"
If Frame1.OptionButton6.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable6"
'If Frame1.OptionButton7.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable7"
'If Frame1.OptionButton8.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable8"
'If Frame1.OptionButton9.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable9"
'If Frame1.OptionButton10.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable10"
'If Frame1.OptionButton11.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable11"
'If Frame1.OptionButton12.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable12"
'If Frame1.OptionButton13.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable13"
'If Frame1.OptionButton14.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable14"
'If Frame1.OptionButton15.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable15"
'If Frame1.OptionButton16.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable16"
'If Frame1.OptionButton17.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable17"
'If Frame1.OptionButton18.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable18"
'If Frame1.OptionButton19.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable19"
'If Frame1.OptionButton20.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable20"
'If Frame1.OptionButton21.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable21"
'If Frame1.OptionButton22.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable22"
'If Frame1.OptionButton23.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable23"
'If Frame1.OptionButton24.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable24"
'If Frame1.OptionButton25.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable25"
'If Frame1.OptionButton26.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable26"
'If Frame1.OptionButton27.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable27"
'If Frame1.OptionButton28.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable28"
'If Frame1.OptionButton29.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable29"
'If Frame1.OptionButton30.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable30"
MsgBox (FromAcc.Value)

'...and so, this code doesn't work right, but I think you get the idea of what I'm trying to do.
'But I'm trying!!  The next bit of code, for CommandButton2, tries to do the same thing,
'but through a different method. But I think you can see how the CommandButton1-method is simple and direct,
'whereas the second method is rather efficient.  I'm trying for efficient, not simple.  Help please?


End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'This code tries to use a counter to cycle through the number attached to each of the OptionButtons,
'and check the value for True or not. When it comes to set the value of FromAcc,
'the same counter is added to the text "LedgerTable", which makes the names of the recognized Tables.
Dim i As Integer
Dim FromAcc As Range
Dim ToAcc As Range

For i = 1 To 6 ' (30)
If Frame1.OptionButton & i.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable" & i
Next i

'For i = 31 To 60
'If Frame2.OptionButton & i.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable" & i
'Next i

MsgBox ("FromAcc:" & FromAcc.Value)   ' (  ... & "      ToAcc:" & ToAcc)


'...See? Completely more efficient, right?  It doesn't work either.
'Do I have to do some fancy thing like,
'copy the Caption of the OptionButton and strip away the "OptionButton" text 
'so the number is the only thing left?
'What 's really annoying is that just when I think I'm getting the hang of it (writing code),
'I come to find that I'm really not. Help? Please? Anyone? -Thanks in advance.
End Sub
`
```

type here

I wrote the code above, but I'm not so good with syntax, so I'm pretty sure is needs a better eye than mine.
And I'm always amazed when I learn a new Function of Excel.  So, maybe there's a better, more direct/efficient approach than what I'm thinking.
Isn't there just a simple function that just returns the name of whatever is selected inside a particular Frame?

I also tried a modified version of the code at:
[Is is possible to grab the number of frames in a userform and the number of optionbuttons in a frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443080/is-is-possible-to-grab-the-number-of-frames-in-a-userform-and-the-number-of-opti)
But when I changed the MsgBox, something messed up.

```
`Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() ' I changed the name from "XX()". I've noted all the changes I made.


Dim c As Control, n As Long ' I changed the variable from nl to n.
Dim FromAcc As Range ' I added this line.

For Each c In UserForm1.Frame1.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is msforms.OptionButton Then
        n1 = n1 + 1
'There was an unnecessary line of code here that I deleted with no loss.
    End If
Next c

' this original line works: MsgBox " option button number = " & n
'my modified version does not:
FromAcc = "LedgerTable" & n
MsgBox = FromAcc.Value


End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are referring to the option buttons here

```vb
For i = 1 To 6 ' (30)
If Frame1.OptionButton & i.Value = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable" & i
Next i
```

is wrong. You are concatenating the **contents** of the Frame1.OptionButton variable (which doesn't exist) and the i variable.

To make your code work, you can concatenate the "OptionButton" **string** and the i variable and attempt to find a control of that name in the Frame1.Controls collection like so:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FromAcc As String
    FromAcc = "No option has been selected"
    For i = 1 To 4 ' (30)
        If Frame1.Controls("OptionButton" & i) = True Then FromAcc = "LedgerTable" & i
    Next i
    
    MsgBox FromAcc
End Sub
```

This, however, will crash if the "OptionButton" & i object is not found. You could implement some error handling or you could try something like this, which should work just as well:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FromAcc As String
    FromAcc = "No option has been selected"
    
    Dim c As Control
    For Each c In Frame1.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "OptionButton" And c.Value = True Then
            FromAcc = "LedgerTable" & Mid(c.Name, 13, Len(c.Name) - 12)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    MsgBox FromAcc
End Sub
```

To make this work, you have to keep the naming convention of "OptionButton" + number but it appears you are already doing that so all should be good.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, then it's the DIM-ing of FramAcc as a STRING is what enables me to concatenate the number with the letters.  Is that right?  And, if so, Why doesn't it have to be Dim-ed as a RANGE?  That's what the concatenation turns out to be; a range.

Comment: And I don't understand the protocol/syntax of Mid(c.Name, 13, Len(c.Name) -12).  I think I need to understand it because, as you said, I have to keep the naming convention of the OptionButton+number, and so I'll need to modify this code for the other Frame (Frame2), in which I'll be determining the ToAcc by corelating OptionButton31 to LedgerTable1, and OptionButton32 to ledger 2 and so on Button60 refers to ledger 30. So, won't I need to change all the "Mid" stuff so it says something like Mid(c.Name - 30, ...?

Comment: -or do I need to Dim a new thing (N) as Number, and then something like: ' If c.Value=True then N=Mid(c.Name, 13,Len(c.Name) - 12'    and then  
' FromAcc="LedgerTable" & N-30 '   ?

Comment: The dim line is not really important, the code would work without it and it is a string, not a range. Why would it be a range? Mid(c.Name, 13, Len(c.Name) -12) takes the characters from the Name of the control, from position 13 to the end. For example for "OptionButton15", it would return "15". Actually, using Right(c.Name, Len(str) - 12) would make more sense here. As for the Frame2 question, it would probably be simplest to use the first approach, have the loop go from 31 to 60 and replace the "LedgerTable" & i with "LedgerTable" & (i - 30). If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I thought it would have needed to be Dim-ed as Range because the name that the concatenation returns is a formal Table; a Named Range. Thanks for explaining the Mid function; I get it now.  But why do they call it Mid?  I mean, the Right(c.Name,Len(str)-12) I understand it just from the way it reads.  It makes it seem as though the Mid function would count a number of characters away from the middle of the string.  ?!?         Anyways, I did use the Mid function because it just worked more easily than the Right function when I brought that Frame2 into play.

Comment: so, I used       For Each c In Frame2.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "OptionButton" And c.Value = True Then
            ToAcc = "LedgerTable" & (Mid(c.Name, 13, Len(c.Name) - 12) - 30)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    MsgBox FromAcc & "     " & ToAcc    ...And it works like a dream!!  Thanks for your help!  You made it so easy for me to understand!  Awesome!  You might have that natural talent thing like great teachers have.  Thanks again.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to mark this question as ANSWERED.  But andrewb really helped; he not only showed me what the proper code would entail, but also explained it in a way I could easily follow along.  Consider this question as ANSWERED -and more than satisfied.

Comment: @MeisterConrad I made a mistake with the Right function...it should have been Right(c.Name, Len(c.Name) - 12). If you want to accept the answer, there should be a checkmark towards the top left of the answer.